# AngularJS directive to extend / augment the element it's applied on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been trying to wrap my head around this without much success. I want to create a directive that can be applied to a button. All it's supposed to do is to add a progress indicator element to the button content, set/ unset a class on the button and toggle ng-disabled.

This is the resulting button I want to create:

```
<button type="submit" 
    ng-click="save()" 
    class="btn btn-default" 
    ng-class="{spinning: saving}" 
    ng-disabled="saving">
    Save
    <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-spinner"></i></span>
</button>
```

And this is what I'd like to write with the directive working as expected:

```
<button type="submit" 
    ng-click="save()" 
    class="btn btn-default" 
    spinning-button spinning="saving">
    Save
</button>
```

I thought this should be really easy with a directive, but I didn't get any satisfying results so far. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y5NF/ . It's working right now but the directive's scope attribute `spinning` is available in the controller's scope because the directive has no scope. If I give the directive a scope, the `ng-click` doesn't work anymore as it is applied to the directive's scope and not the controller's scope.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this seems to be not possible - and in my narrow use case also not necessary, though it would have been nice... Thank you KayakDave for clarifying. Also helpful was this one: [AngularJS - ngClick, custom directive, and isolated scope issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775209/angularjs-ngclick-custom-directive-and-isolated-scope-issue).

I ended up with this directive:

```
.directive('spinnerButton', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass("has-spinner");
            element.append(' <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-spinner"></i></span>');

            scope.$watch(attrs.spinnerButton, function(value) {
                element.toggleClass("spinning", value);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

and this HTML to use the directive:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="signUp()" class="btn btn-default"
    spinner-button="signupInProgress" ng-disabled="loginInProgress">
    Sign up
</button>
```

It takes the button as is and adds the `has-spinner` class as well as the inner `<span>` at the end of the button title.

The CSS I used is based on http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewDryga/GY6LC/ from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988830/61478

Comment: hi i just looked into this directive just curious what is signupInProgress?? thanks

Comment: `signupInProgress` is just a variable that's declared somewhere in the controller that determines if the class `spinning` is applied to the button or not (see the `$watch` call in the JS part)

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1- In your directive `spinning="saveOngoing"` makes `attrs.spinning` equal to `saveOngoing`.  So your $watch on `attrs.scope` results in a watch on `saveOngoing`. Once you use an isolate scope `saveOngoing` isn't visible. You'd rather watch `spinning` as that's what you've brought into your scope.

So switch your `$watch` from this:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.spinning, function(value) {..})
```

to

```
scope.$watch('spinning', function(value) {..})
```

Here's your fiddle updated with that:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Y5NF/2/

You'll see the watch is now triggered when you click on the buttons.

2- This line:

```
<p>Spinning (from the directive scope): {{spinning}}</p>
```

Doesn't work with an isolate scope because only the DOM element with the isolate scope can see `spinning`.  `spinning="saveOngoing"` is setting up an association such that inside the directive the variable is known as `spinning` while on the controller scope it's known as `saveOngoing`.

Thus, since `<p>` is outside the isolate scope of your directive it doesn't know anything about `spinning`.

Without an isolate scope `spinning="saveOngoing"` creates a second variable on the parent scope.  So you end up with two variables `saveOngoing` and `spinning` (which is why that line worked in your non-isolate scope example).

Comment: Thank you. I was playing around with different options about 1. I guess the real kicker is 2. So it's not possible to have a directive access its own isolated scope and also have other attributes / directives access the controller's or parent scope?